# How can I use Depth First Search to list numbers from a phone pad?

Tags: java, python, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

I have been trying to solve the phone number pad listing problem using Java and Python. The code I wrote can be found below.

Given a digit and a length variable, returns the list of numbers that will be generated from a phone pad.

Example:
    f(4, 3) will return ['474', '454', '478', '414', '412', '458', '456', '452']

This is what I have tried so far (in Java):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PhonePadExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer selectedDigit = 4;
        Integer maxIteration = 4;

        PhonePadNumberGenerator generator = new PhonePadNumberGenerator();

        List<List<Integer>> result = generator.findUniqueNumberFromPhonePad(selectedDigit, maxIteration);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

class PhonePadNumberGenerator {

    private List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Integer> subresult = new ArrayList<>();

    private Map<DirectionEnum, DirectionEnum> opposites = new HashMap<>();

    private List<PhonePadWithDirection> phonePadWithDirectionList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PhonePadNumberGenerator() {
        initPad();
        initOpposites();
    }

    private static Map<DirectionEnum, Integer> createMap(Integer up, Integer down, Integer left, Integer right) {

        return new HashMap<DirectionEnum, Integer>() {
            {
                put(DirectionEnum.UP, up);
                put(DirectionEnum.DOWN, down);
                put(DirectionEnum.LEFT, left);
                put(DirectionEnum.RIGHT, right);
            }
        };
    }

    private void initPad() {
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(0, createMap(8, null, null, null)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(1, createMap(null, 4, null, 2)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(2, createMap(null, 5, 1, 3)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(3, createMap(null, 6, 2, null)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(4, createMap(1, 7, null, 5)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(5, createMap(2, 8, 4, 6)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(6, createMap(3, 5, 9, null)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(7, createMap(4, null, null, 8)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(8, createMap(5, 0, 7, 9)));
        phonePadWithDirectionList.add(new PhonePadWithDirection(9, createMap(6, null, 8, null)));
    }

    private void initOpposites() {
        opposites.put(DirectionEnum.UP, DirectionEnum.DOWN);
        opposites.put(DirectionEnum.DOWN, DirectionEnum.UP);
        opposites.put(DirectionEnum.LEFT, DirectionEnum.RIGHT);
        opposites.put(DirectionEnum.RIGHT, DirectionEnum.LEFT);
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> findUniqueNumberFromPhonePad(Integer selectedDigit, Integer maxIteration) {

        PhonePadWithDirection pad = phonePadWithDirectionList.get(selectedDigit);

        for (DirectionEnum direction : DirectionEnum.values()) {

            subresult.add(pad.getNumber());
            recursivelyFindPath(pad, direction, maxIteration);

            result.add(subresult);
            subresult = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        // remove subresult which doesn't fulfil max iteration (which contains less elements) //java 8 solution
        result.removeIf(r -> r.size() < maxIteration);

        return result;
    }

    private void recursivelyFindPath(PhonePadWithDirection pad, DirectionEnum directionEnum, Integer maxIteration) {

        if (subresult.size() < maxIteration) {

            System.out.printf("With Number %d and New Direction %s%n", pad.getNumber(), directionEnum.name());

            Integer valueAtNewDirection = pad.getValue(directionEnum);

            if (valueAtNewDirection != null) {

                PhonePadWithDirection newPad = phonePadWithDirectionList.get(valueAtNewDirection);

                // should not go back to the same number again
                if (subresult.indexOf(newPad.getNumber()) == -1) {

                    subresult.add(valueAtNewDirection); printPretty(newPad);

                    for (DirectionEnum direction : DirectionEnum.values()) {
                        if (direction != opposites.get(directionEnum))
                            recursivelyFindPath(newPad, direction, maxIteration);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void printPretty(PhonePadWithDirection pad) {

        System.out.printf("For Number = %d : Up = %d, Down = %d, Left = %d, Right = %d%n",
                pad.getNumber(),
                pad.getValue(DirectionEnum.UP),
                pad.getValue(DirectionEnum.DOWN),
                pad.getValue(DirectionEnum.LEFT),
                pad.getValue(DirectionEnum.RIGHT)
        );
    }
}

class PhonePadWithDirection {

    private Integer number;
    private Map<DirectionEnum, Integer> directionWithValue = new HashMap<>();

    public PhonePadWithDirection(Integer number, Map<DirectionEnum, Integer> directionWithValue) {
        this.number = number;
        this.directionWithValue = directionWithValue;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public Map<DirectionEnum, Integer> getDirectionWithValue() {
        return directionWithValue;
    }

    public Integer getValue(DirectionEnum directionEnum) {
        return this.getDirectionWithValue().get(directionEnum);
    }
}

enum DirectionEnum {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using DFS(which involves recursion, backtracking), you can generate all the possible permutations of length n. For each permutation, traverse it decide whether it's a possible pattern or not. In this way you can count them.

Comment: @Ralf: I have added the link to the code I wrote

Answer (score 3):

You can use `backtracking` to generate all possible digits. Here's a possible implementation: https://ideone.com/Qiy3mt. As visible the in the pseudocode below, the function `f(d, n)` does a recursive depth-first search to explore all the possible digits which fit in the given constraint.

```
pad = [
    "123",
    "456",
    "789",
    " 0 "
]

def valid(i, j):
    if i >= 4 or i < 0 or j < 0 or j >= 3:
        return False
    return (pad[i][j] != ' ')

delta_x = [-1, 1, 0, 0]
delta_y = [0, 0, -1, 1]

def f(d, n):
    if n == 1:
        return [d]
    if n <= 0:
        return []

    x = None; y = None

    # The following line of code can be replaced by a dict lookup which
    # stores the indices of every digit, say { 5: (1, 1), 1: (0, 0) .. }
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if pad[i][j] == str(d):
                x = i; y = j

    digits = []
    for i in range(0,4):
        next_x = x + delta_x[i]
        next_y = y + delta_y[i]
        if valid(next_x, next_y):
            digits.extend(f(pad[next_x][next_y], n - 1))

    return [str(d) + str(w) for w in digits]

print(f(5, 1))
print(f(1, 3))
print(f(0, 3))
```